# Get raw body from HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a spring web service and sometimes a client calls it with a bad body, and spring throws HttpMessageNotReadableException.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler({ HttpMessageNotReadableException.class })
public GenericErrorResp exceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
    log.error("Invalid body", e);
    return new GenericErrorResp();
}
```

Is it possible to get the original body? I have try with:

```
InputStream body = e.getHttpInputMessage().getBody();
```

but `inputStream` have no more bytes and mark/reset are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Update controller code like:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException.class)
private ResponseEntity<TransactionInfo> exception(UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException exception) 
{
    TransactionInfo transactionInfo = new TransactionInfo(ErrorStatus.FAIL);
    log.error(exception.getMessage());
    transactionInfo.addErrorList(new ErrorField(ErrorMessageBuilder.retriveCode(exception.getMessage()), 
                                                ErrorMessageBuilder.retriveMessage(exception.getMessage())));
    transactionInfo.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(transactionInfo, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

**This is my TransactionInfo:**

```java
public class TransactionInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5920854604468221743L;

    private ErrorStatus status;
    private Object responseData;
    private Integer statusCode;
    private List<ErrorField> errorList = new ArrayList<ErrorField>();

}
```

Let me know if you have any concern.

Comment: This code does not retrieve any http body from HttpMessageNotReadableException